# Parse byteBuffer in Websphere MQ Exit

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I'm trying to build a custom mq exit to archive messages that hit a queue. I have the following code.

```
class MyMqExits implements WMQSendExit, WMQReceiveExit{

@Override
public ByteBuffer channelReceiveExit(MQCXP arg0, MQCD arg1, ByteBuffer arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if ( arg2){
        def _bytes = arg2.array()
        def results = new String(_bytes)
        println results;
    }

    return arg2;
}
...
```

The content of the message (header/body) is in the byte buffer, along with some unreadable binary information. How can I parse the message (including the body and the queue name) from arg2? We've gone through IBM's documentation, but haven't found an object or anything that makes this easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the following two points:

1) Your sender application has not hard coded the queue name where it puts messages. So you can change the application configuration to send messages to a different object.

2) MessageId of the archived message is not important, only message body is important.

Then one alternative I can think of is to create an Alias queue that resolves to a Topic and use two subscribers to receive messages.

1) Subscriber 1: An administratively defined durable subscriber with a queue provided to receive messages. Provide the same queue name from which your existing consumer application is receiving messages.

2) Subscriber 2: Another administratively defined durable subscriber with queue provided. You can write a simple java application to get messages from this queue and archive.

3) Both subscribers subscribe to the same topic.

Here are steps:

```
// Create a topic
define topic(ANY.TOPIC) TOPICSTR('/ANY_TOPIC')
// Create an alias queue that points to above created topic
define qalias(QA.APP) target(ANY.TOPIC) targtype(TOPIC)
// Create a queue for your application that does business logic. If one is available already then no need to create.
define ql(Q.BUSLOGIC)
// Create a durable subscription with destination queue as created in previous step.
define sub(SB.BUSLOGIC) topicstr('/ANY_TOPIC') dest(Q.BUSLOGIC)
// Create a queue for application that archives messages.
define ql(Q.ARCHIVE)
// Create another subscription with destination queue as created in previous step.
define sub(SB.ARCHIVE) topicstr('/ANY_TOPIC') dest(Q.ARCHIVE)
```

Write a simple MQ Java/JMS application to get messages from `Q.ARCHIVE` and archive messages.

Answer (score 3):

A receive exit is not going to give you the whole message. Send and receive exits operate on the transmission buffers sent/received by channels. These will contain various protocol flows which are not documented because the protocol is not public, and part of those protocol flows will be chunks of the messages broken down to fit into 32Kb chunks.

You don't give enough information in your question for me to know what type of channel you are using, but I'm guessing it's on the client side since you are writing it in Java and that is the only environment where that is applicable.

Writing the exit at the client side, you'll need to be careful you deal with the cases where the message is not successfully put to the target queue, and you'll need to manage syncpoints etc.

If you were using QMgr-QMgr channels, you should use a message exit to capture the MQXR_MSG invocations where the whole message is given to you. If you put any further messages in a channel message exit, the messages you put are included in the channel's Syncpoint and so committed if the original messages were committed.

Since you are using client-QMgr channels, you could look at an API Exit on the QMgr end (currently client side API Exits are only supported for C clients) and catch all the MQPUT calls. This exit would also give you the MQPUT return codes so you could code your exit to look out for, and deal with failed puts.

Of course, writing an exit is a complicated task, so it may be worth finding out if there are any pre-written tools that could do this for you instead of starting from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

I fully agree with Morag & Shashi, wrong approach.  There is an open source project called Message Multiplexer (MMX) that will get a message from a queue and output it to one or more queues. Context information is maintained across the message put(s). For more info on MMX go to: http://www.capitalware.com/mmx_overview.html

If you cannot change the source or target queues to insert MMX into the mix then an API Exit may do the trick.  Here is a blog posting about message replication via an API Exit: http://www.capitalware.com/rl_blog/?p=3304

Answer (score 1):

This is quite an old question but it's worth replying with an update that's relevant to MQ 9.2.3 or later. There is a new feature called Streaming Queues (see https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=scenarios-streaming-queues) and one of the use-cases it is designed to support is putting a copy of every message sent to a given queue, to an alternative queue. Another application can then consume the duplicate messages and archive them separately to the application that is processing the original messages.